# Flutter - W/ClipboardManager(10439): not support ClipboardEx

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building an app using `Flutter`, and when I run it and try to edit the `TextField`'s i get the following error:

```
W/ClipboardManager(10439): not support ClipboardEx
W/System.err(10439): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.ClipData.getItemCount()' on a null object reference
W/System.err(10439):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1626)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.content.IClipboard$Stub$Proxy.getPrimaryClip(IClipboard.java:197)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.content.ClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip(ClipboardManager.java:269)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:283)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:24)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:82)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/System.err(10439):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
W/System.err(10439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
W/System.err(10439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(10439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err(10439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Thanks in advance if anyone knows how to fix this! :)

*Github* Project: https://github.com/RafaelSetton/Flutter-Routing-and-DB

**Note: The app is mostly in *portuguese.***